# RxJava 2: Observable.create() wait until async code is finished using Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

I am wrapping some async code using `Observable.create(...)`. The async code needs to be "active" for five seconds, and then it should be stopped. This is how I am currently stopping it:

```
Observable.<MyObject>create(emitter -> {

    // Some async code

    emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(() -> {
        // Stop the above async code
    }));

    // Wait for 5 seconds until the async code above has had enough time to finish its task.
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
        // Stop the above async code
        emitter.setDisposable(null);
    }
})...
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way because `Thread.sleep(5000)` is used. Is there a better way to do this with some RxJava code?

Comment: What is this async code? Can't it signal if it has completed on its own? There is a timed `take()` overload that can stop a source but you still have to have a `setDisposable` in `create`.

Comment: @akarnokd The async code is Android's Network Service Discovery (https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html#discover). It scans for devices in the local network until the listener is unregistered. I just want to scan once, so I manually need to unregister the listener after five seconds, and then call `emitter.onComplete()`. Does `take()` complete and dispose the observable?

Comment: Please look at the Javadoc and the diagram: [take()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#take-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a timed overload of `take` that allows you to have items from a source until the specified time elapses:

```
Observable.<MyObject>create(emitter -> {

    // Some async code

    emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(() -> {
        // Stop the above async code
    }));
})
.take(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You still have to setup the `Disposable` in `create`.